# Quelle est la meilleure traduction de « vanilla » en programmation ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

En programmation, on voit souvent l'emploi du terme *vanilla* pour indiquer l'absence de framework. Par exemple, par opposition à jQuery, on parle de *vanilla JS*.

Quelle est la meilleure traduction possible de cette expression en français ? Je pensais à *pur Javascript*, mais existe-t-il plus parlant ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

En ce qui me concerne, je parle de *Python standard* pour faire référence au fait que je ne me sers que de la bibliothèque standard. J'aurais tendance à comprendre *JS pur* comme « JS uniquement, pas mélangé avec d'autres langages ».

Comment: (+1) C'est juste, il faut faire attention de ne pas introduire de confusion avec le *full JS* (création de page intégralement en JS, sans une structure, HTML ou autre, préexistante), ce qui ne présuppose ni n'interdit l'utilisation de librairies.

Answer (score 11):

Personellement il m'arrive d'utiliser les expressions "*de base*" ou "*natif*". Exemple : "*JavaScript de base*", "*C++ de base*" (sans Qt ou Boost)... Je trouve que ça traduit bien le côté "sans artifices supplémentaires" de "*vanilla*".

Comment: Avec *de base*, j'ai l'impression que l'on n'utilise pas les fonctionnalités avancées du langage, mais plutôt celle connues par la plupart des développeurs.

Answer (score 7):

J'utilise moi aussi **JS pur** (voire l'expression anglophone directement) dans les contextes où mon interlocuteur a la culture technique permettant de saisir l'expression. Mais ce n'est effectivement pas idéal à mon sens, ça pourrait introduire des confusions de temps en temps, et ça connote une espèce de jugement de valeur implicite sur l'utilisation des librairies Javascript un peu gênant.

Si l'on voulait désambiguer le terme, peut-être pourrait-on parler de... *JS dans son plus simple appareil* (OK, probablement trop long), ou de **JS nu** ?

Answer (score 4):

En général, l'expression anglaise «vanilla ...» fait référence à la saveur de base des aliments en épicerie; par exemple, le yogourt. En français, on utilise souvent l'adjectif «nature» à la place. Mais en programmation, comme indiqué dans les autres réponses, «pur»  ou «natif» sont ce que j'utilise.

Comment: Une question me turlupine: comment dit-on _yaourt à la vanille_ en anglais, si _vanilla yogurt_ veut dire _yaourt nature_?

Comment: Pour le yogourt en particulier, je crois que c'est ambigue: la vanille est souvent ajoutée au mélange *nature*; j'aurais tendence à penser que c'est de là que viens l'expression, mais je ne saurais pas comment trouver des références pour ça. Dans le traducteur de Google, *nature* est traduit comme *plain*, et *vanille* comme *vanilla*. Somme toute, je crois qu'en anglais *vanilla yogourt* veut dire *yogourt à la vanille*, même si dans d'autre contexte *vanilla* veut dire *plain*. C'est en français, où *nature* en est venu à vouloir dire *à la vanille* dans ce contexte.

Comment: @mouviciel: [Plain vs Vanilla yogurt](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176388/whats-the-difference-between-vanilla-and-plain-when-talking-about-yogurts). Plain yogurt = sans arôme, vanilla yogurt = arôme vanille. Il n'y a donc pas d’ambiguïté, en revanche il y en a une en français: Elle porte sur *arôme*, car [d'après cette source](https://www.mondevanille.com/fr/content/category/5-formes-commerciales), *arôme vanille* signifie que l'arôme est artificiel et *yaourt vanille* que l'arôme est naturel. Personne n'y comprend rien, c'est bien pratique !

Comment: Je pense que c'est en référence à la glace plutôt qu'au yaourt. Une glace "standard" est à la vanille...

Answer (score 3):

J'aurais aussi opté pour *"de base"* ou *"natif"* et, plus généralement, *"sans …"* + de ce dont il s'agit.

Comme *"sans framework"* ou, dans le cas de jeux-vidéos, *"sans mods"* par exemple.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que cette réponse ajoute à celle de air-dex ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je propose mon point de vue personnel et air-dex n'a pas proposé *"sans"* + quelque chose comme solution (je trouve que c'était important à souligner) mais à chaque fois qu'il a utilisé l'expression *"sans"* + quelque chose dans sa réponse c'était uniquement à titre explicatif pour expliquer sa réponse. Du moins c'est mon point de vue/ressenti. Cordialement.